# Proof of $\sigma$ subadditivity of Labesgue outer measure.

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\{A_n\}$ a sequence of subsets of $\Bbb R$. I want to prove $m^*(\cup_n A_n)\le \sum_nm^*(A_n)$. So, given $\varepsilon>0$, by the definition of Labesgue outer measure $m^*(A_n)=\inf\{\sum_n l(a_n,b_n):A_n\subset \cup_n(a_n,b_n) \}$. For each $n\in \Bbb N$, there exists a sequence $\{I_{n,k}\}_k$ of open interval in $\Bbb R$ such that $m^*(A_n)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}}>\sum_kl(I_{n,k})$. Since $\cup_n A_n \subset \cup_n\cup_kI_{n,k}$, we have $m^*(\cup_n A_n)< m^*(\cup_n\cup_kI_{n,k})$.

I have problem how to show that $m^*(\cup_n\cup_kI_{n,k})=\sum_n m^*(\cup_kI_{n,k})=\sum_n \sum_k m^*(I_{n,k})=\sum_{n,k}l(I_{n,k})$.
I know that $m^*(I)=l(I)$ when $I$ is an open interval in $\Bbb R$, but in this proof, union of open intervals may not be open interval.

Answer (score 0):

$\cup_n\cup_k I_{n,k}$ is itself  a coutable union of open intervals. You can, if you want. express it as a union of  a sigle sequence of open intervals using a bijection $f$  from $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. [The union is nothing but $\cup_i I_{f^{-1}(i)}$]